# How to change the color of a set of nodes?

Tags: python, colors, nodes, networkx

I have the following graph. I want to set a different node color for avengers and guardians of galaxy  but the following doesn't work. Do you have any suggestions?

```
g = nx.DiGraph()
g.add_nodes_from(guardians,node_color='b')
g.add_edges_from(guardians_links)

g.add_nodes_from(avengers,node_color='y')
g.add_edges_from(avengers_links)

plt.figure(figsize=(12,10))
nx.draw_random(g)
plt.show() # display
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `nx.draw_random(g)` with

```
pos = nx.random_layout(g)
nx.draw(g,pos=pos, nodelist = guardians, node_color='b')
nx.draw(g,pos=pos, nodelist = avengers, node_color='y')
```

And you don't really need to be assigning node colors when you add the nodes.

Here are the instructions for [`nx.draw`](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw).  The optional keywords are described in the documentation for [`nx.draw_networkx`](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx).

Comment: I get this 
TypeError: draw() got multiple values for keyword argument 'pos'

Comment: oops - I meant to have the call be to `nx.draw(...)` rather than `nx.draw_random(...)`.  See the edited code.  Should work.